# Do we consider total/partial participation for the whole lifetime of the database in entity relationship diagram?

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

Do we consider total/partial participation for the whole lifetime of the database in entity relationship diagram?

I mean sometimes during a certain time of the database the participation between an entity type and the relationship could not be hold but it normally does exist

For example, a relationship between course and section at the university. The participation of section is total for sure. But what about the course? Usually when a major is specified, the courses of the major are specified and exist in the database but at a certain time the course do not have any sections, which is the case before students register to the major or between semesters, at the vacation time ...etc. In this case do we consider it partial? Because it is partial at a certain time but while the semester holds it is total.

Comment: Diagrams serve development purposes, so why would you bother, besides pedantry? You can can make a course partial and have two entity types "Major Course" for active students' courses and "Historical Course" for students and courses from previous years

Comment: @AlexLarionov Thank you for your reply. What I am asking is whether the participation is partial or total considering the scenario I've specified ... so I need such precise answer. In addition,  I don't think making two entity types for the course is a good idea, they refer to the same type and they have the same attributes